NextJS 14 App Page Freezing UI using own custom developed NPM Packages in ReactJS using ViteJS
I have nextjs 14 app using mui, I have created my own npm packages for it's components in reactjs using vitejs, that is running perfectly fine.
Problem:
The issue I'm facing is that when i open inspect dev tools in browser and run the app it's start rendering too much slower, like if i open settings drawer it open after 5-7 seconds of setting button click on dashboard, and same case when i switch from one route to other. it only happens while keeping open dev tools in browser and when i close the devtools it works perfectly fine like a superfast app what it needs to be.
Note:
this super slower rendering only happens on pages where i have integrated custom npm packages by linking locally using npm command,
npm link
also this happens only when devtools are open in browser.
Did anyone faced this issue, or know how to get it fix?
Also if someone know better way to create own npm packages in nextjs/reactjs other then vitejs, also please help me to get it fix.
I tried to create own npm packages in reactjs using vitejs, then integrate them in nextjs 14 app, I need someone to help me to get the slower app issue when keeping open devtools of browser and helps me to create better npm packages.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

okay I will share code
